# Array performance question

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

I am very familiar with STL vector (and other container) performance guarantees, however I can't seem to find anything concrete about plain arrays.

Are pointer arithmetic and [] methods constant or linear time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are constant time. (Same as `vector`.)

When you say `a[b]`, it becomes `*(a + b)`. Both (pointer arithmetic) addition and dereferencing are constant time.

When adding an integer to a pointer, it moves that many elements over:

```
T* p; size_t i;

T* q = p + i; // same as:
T* q = reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + i * sizeof(T));
```

Every operation in there is constant time.

Comment: Silly question - constant time for total operation ? So would (pObj + 1) and (pObj + 10) take the same amount of time?

Comment: @Konrad Yes - pointer arithmetic is just arithmetic, 1 + 1 takes the same time as 1 + 10.

Comment: Thank you, I thought so but was having a brain fail moment. Thanks!

Comment: Just an observation.  Not only is the performance of operator[] the same for vector as it is for plain types, it is the same for the same reason.  `vector` implements the data store as a C-style array.

Answer (score 2):

A vector is effectively a wrapper around an array, so they should both provide the same performance guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic is constant - it's usually a single multiplication and addition to base. [] is a kind of pointer arithmetic as well.